# Add Solaris utf-8 support for Postgresql

Tags: solaris, locale, unicode, postgresql, nexenta

I need to use utf-8, but "locale -a" produces:

```
C
POSIX
iso_8859_1
```

the os is:

```
SunOS cteraportal 5.11 NexentaOS_134f i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

Additional info:

```
root@cteraportal:~# dpkg -l locales
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Installed/Config-f/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/t-aWait/T-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Hold/Reinst-required/X=both-problems (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  locales        1:5.11.134-1   Transitional package
```

How can i add utf-8?

**More info**
Back to this issue after some time...
I installed 2 locale packages:
SUNWeu8os
SUNWeuluf
( other packages from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/html/817-0545/eezez.html#scrolltoc fail on dependency packages that I didn't find )

now locale -e shows:

```
C  
POSIX  
en_US.UTF-8  
iso_8859_1
```

but building a postgresql db with en_US.UTF-8 still isn't supported.
I need to find and install the right packages for nexenta